Troubleshooting PXE Boot Issues with WDS and DHCP on the Same Server
I am trying to preform an image capture for one of my PCs. I cannot get the image capture process to work.
On the client PC I am running C:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown /unattend: .\sysprep_unattend.xml. After this the "Sysprep is working…" dialog appears and the system shuts down.  When I turn the system back on and try to Start PXE over IPV4 it does not work.
For the setup:
I have WDS and DHCP are on the same server. In DHCP I have 3 IPV4 server options selected. 060 PXE Client set to PXEClient, 066 Boot Server Host Name set to the IP that WDS and DHCP are on, and 067 Bootfile Name set to Boot\x64\Images\boot.wim. On WDS, for the server properties in the DHCP tab, I have 'Do not listen on DHCP ports' checked and 'Configure DHCP options to indicate that this is also a PXE server' checked as well. I also have inbound and outbound rules set to allow ports 67, 68, 69, and 4011 set. Both the Client and the WDS server are on the same Domain. Am I missing anything in the setup?
When I try booting the client by PXE over IPV4 I get this Information:

In the Deployment-Services-Diagnostics Debug log I see only two errors:

[base\eco\wds\wdswdsmgmt\src\wdsdirectoryservicesusepolicy.cpp:295] Expression:,Win32 Error=0x2
[base\eco\wds\wdswdsmgmt\src\wdsdirectoryservicesusepolicy.cpp:306] Expression:,Win32 Error=0x2


When I filter wireshark by bootp, I only see DHCP Discover and not any DHCP Offer, Request, and Acknowledgment packets.


